# Pesquisa local com detalhe a cada letra digitada - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

A cada letra digitada aparece uma bola branca no meio do app (pelo jeito é atualizando a lista), gostaria de poder não ter isso.

O erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código:

```
//Pesquisa localmente a cada letra digitada
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Letra Maiúscula
    MainSearchBar.Text = MainSearchBar.Text.ToUpper();

    //Pesquisa a cada dígito
    lstProduto.BeginRefresh();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.NewTextValue))
    {
        lstProduto.ItemsSource = produtos;
    }
    else
    {
        lstProduto.ItemsSource = produtos.Where(i => i.DESCRICAO.Contains(e.NewTextValue));
    }
    lstProduto.EndRefresh();
}
```

Comment: Coloque como resposta por favor (deu certo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu método `OnTextChanged` você está ativando a propriedade `IsRefreshing` da sua `ListView`.

Aqui:

```
//Pesquisa localmente a cada letra digitada
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    lstProduto.BeginRefresh();
    ...
    lstProduto.EndRefresh();
}
```

No intervalo dessas duas chamadas (`BeginRefresh` e `EndRefresh`), o componente `Listview` apresenta o indicador de 'ocupado'.

Basta remover essas duas chamadas que o indicador não aparecerá mais.